# What is this connector?

Tags: windows, screens

I want to add screens to the wood-framed casement windows in my house, and while examining the existing frames, I found what appear to be connectors for screens (the oblong bit on the right in the photo). Only the windows that open have these. The fixed-pane windows don’t, which reinforces my assumption that these are for screens.

I’m planning to build custom screens myself, and I’d love to use these connectors if possible, to avoid drilling into the window frames. Does anybody know what these are called and what I would use to connect into them? The windows were made by Pella, if that helps.

[image: Photo of a wood casement window frame with an oblong connector oriented vertically on one side.]

Comment: You have it right. It's a slot that the little tab on the screens slips into to hold the screen in place.  They're common across many window vendors, Pella, Anderson, and others.  Was going to make this an answer, but since it's straightforward a comment will do.  Saves the administrators the trouble of turning an answer into a comment because it was too simple <wink>.

Comment: Good to know I’m on the right track. Do you know what the tabs that slip into them are called?

Comment: No.  Note that they are integrated into the frame of the screen.  There is a slot in the screen frame that accepts the tab.  They are not an add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have your answer right in your picture:

[image]

My guess is that if you investigate that swing out tab mechanism you will discover that when it is folded down to the inner window pane frame that it has a tab that goes right into a similar slot.

Comment: You’re exactly right. I hadn’t thought to look at those more closely. I’ll need to get a set of those and figure out how to integrate them into my custom screens. Thanks!